# How to fix Flutter app showing in foreground when phone screen is locked

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

I had a problem during the development of my mobile application in flutter. My app was always in the foreground (even when the phone was locked).

If this happens to you, I have the solution for you:

1- Open your AndroidManifest.xml file.
2- Find your app's activity tag.
3- Change the value of the android:showWhenLocked attribute to false to indicate that your app should not be displayed in the foreground when the phone screen is locked.

The code :
android:showWhenLocked="false"

Comment: Instead of answering your own question in the question itself, please post an answer. You can answer your own question, and you can also mark it as the accepted answer. This way it is much more clear that the question has been answered.

Comment: Hello, no I couldn't do it because I didn't have enough points to do it. I was new to the forum and I was refused to respond by comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution for you!

1. Open your AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Find your app's activity tag.
3. Change the value of the `android:showWhenLocked` attribute to `false` to indicate that your app should not be displayed in the foreground when the phone screen is locked.

The code:

```xml
android:showWhenLocked="false"
```